# How to spring-boot:repacakge to Jar and War from a codebase with single maven command

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I want to generate both Jar and War spring-boot packages from the same codebase via single maven command `mvn install`

We are currently generating individual Jar and War spring-boot packages from the same codebase with different profiles in pom via `mvn install -PJar && mvn install -PWar`,
Currently i'm able to generate Jar and War packages by packaging war. The flow is like below.

`Compile - > Package Jar -> Package War -> Repackage Jar to spring-boot Jar`.

I'm unable to achieve the next step `Repackage War to spring-boot War`

```
        <!-- Jar is the default package -->                 
        <!-- Package War -->        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-war</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                 <execution>
                    <id>build-info</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The above is creating Jar and War packages and only spring-boot Jar package, spring-boot War package is not created. 
i have tried using `classifiers` in execution configuration to bind the war packaging with war repackaging in spring-boot, But the repackage looks for `${artifact-id}-${classifier}.jar` instead of `${artifact-id}-${classifier}.war` and skips repackaging of war.

Comment: Why do you need both a jar and war?

Comment: Same code base has to be deployed to PAAS and JBOSS. So Jar for PASS and War for JBOSS

Comment: The WAR is also executable, you don’t need an additional JAR for that. You can just do ‘java -jar your.war’ and it Will work.

Comment: Thanks for that. I really appreciate your help. But i wanted to know is there a way to repackage both jar and war from single command. We have explored all other possibility of using same package for various env but  it doesn't fit into our business needs.

Comment: Again why? You can just run the war you don't need to package a jar for that.